# Best SQL code to calculate future values in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named #info that looks like this:

```
name        start        delta
 n1         200.0         43.0
 n2        6000.0         87.0
 n3         739.0        129.0

create table #info (name sysname, startV float, changeV float);
```

But I need to create a table that takes the values from the #info table and calculates future values for each name in table above. So we have a start value and a amount change or a delta amount. So I need to generate a table that calculates both a future date and a future amount. The date is being incremented 2 weeks and go up to a year in the future. On 01/04/2013, we are starting with STARTV value and increasing the start value by the change value. So basically, the output will look like so:

```
    date        name        amount
01/04/2013      n1           200
01/18/2013      n1           243
02/01/2013      n1           286
 .......        ...          ....
01/04/2014      n1           673
01/04/2013      n2           6000       
01/18/2013      n2           6087
02/01/2013      n2           6174
 .......        ...          ....
01/04/2014      n2           6957
01/04/2013      n3           739   
 .......        ...          ....
```

Here is the SQL code I came up with so far, by it only does it for the n1 value, it doesn't list the values for n2 or n3... What do I need to change?

```
DECLARE @dd DATE
SET @dd = '01/04/2013';
SELECT TOP 24 DATEADD(week, 2*rn, @dd) ,*
    FROM (SELECT rn=(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)) -1
       FROM sys.columns ) c cross apply  
 (select d.dbname , d.startV+((rn+1)*d.changeV) as mm from #info d)  a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;with cte as (
    select convert(date, '20130401', 112) as Date, i.name, i.startV as amount, 1 as num
    from #info as i

    union all

    select dateadd(wk, 2, c.date) as Date, c.name, c.amount + i.changeV, c.num + 1 as num
    from cte as c
        inner join #info as i on i.name = c.name
    where c.num < 24
)
select *
from cte
order by name asc, date asc
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd6a5/4)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a hard understanding recursive CTEs. Maybe this will help me get it in my head... Thank you!